# Node content not available to anonymous users

Tags: nodes, users

I'm having some trouble with viewing my nodes as an anonymous user. When not logged in as admin, I am still able to access the URL of the node, but the content (other than the title) is blank. I've spent a lot of time looking around the permissions, but I can't seem to resolve this issue. The problem exists when accessing the node directly or through a view.

The below example uses nodes with the Link field type, but I'm also having the same problem with my text and file fieldtypes.

This is what displays in a particular view as anonymous:
[image: Grid view of Links, each title is a node with X number of links below it, links aren't displaying]

The same view, logged in as admin:
[image: View logged in as admin, links are displayed fully]

Hopefully an easy fix, any recommendations would be great!

Comment: As an anonymous user, open the page, active the firebug and check if the `DIV` of the fields are created or not, and if yes, check what is inside it. it would be better of you display its screenshot in your question.

Comment: Are you using the [field permissions](http://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions) module?

Comment: Field Permissions is not installed on my site.

Answer (score 0):

Try rebuilding site content permissions. Every now again that has tripped me. In D7 you can find it @ **/admin/reports/status/rebuild**.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, it was the Organic Groups Field Access module causing the problems. Disabling the module allowed anonymous users to view the full node properly.